# Architecture for Web-App development aimed at aiding interoperability between CMS systems. Has it been done?

Tags: drupal, architecture, joomla, content-management-system, interop

I'm thinking about attempting to design a new framework architecture aimed at allowing a web app to later be easily ported into a system such as Drupal or Joomla while maintaining the independence of the original app such that updates to core functionality would require only one release or otherwise minimal extra work.

Before I start on this however, I would like to see what work has previously been done that comes closest to what I am proposing. So an answer to this question would come in the form of a reference to the most similar work or if possible a definitive 'no' that this has not been done before.

Clarification by example: MediaWiki is a common web app that has become one of the most highly recommended of its kind. However, site admins building their sites with Drupal would be required to hack MediaWiki in order for it to play nicely with Drupal in terms of sharing a user base for example. Imagine that MediaWiki has decided to do a complete rebuild of their system, what design could be used to make this interaction simply require a Drupal module or Joomla component and thus make MediaWiki available to more users?

I'm using MediaWiki as just an example, I think modules and components already exist that solve this particular problem but I hope I am able to get my idea across. It is a problem I have encountered many times during web development now that CMS systems are appearing more and more enterprise-like.

Thanks!
godwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) is an OASIS Specification that you can use to imrprove the data portability and interoperability of a CMS. If your system has (or your provide) a CMIS interface, you can move content to / from other CMS systems that also provide CMIS interfaces.

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services
- http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=cmis

Comment: Great, looks fairly different than what I'm proposing, mainly in that it's much more SOA based and that it's designed to work for proprietary systems which may or may not be on the same server.

Thanks!